# Bot Framework Composer - Read App Settings

Tags: c#, botframework, bot-framework-composer

I need to manage some settings from Bot Framework Composer like BaseURL for my REST Service.

I open this issue in [Github Repo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/2317).

I search on Bot Framework Composer docs but I haven't found anything.

Has anyone ever set settings on the page where MicrosoftAppId, Luis, QnA are also placed?
I would like to save the settings there and read them in the composer.
Is this a feature already implemented?

Answer (score 2):

You can access it throught the settings memory scope. Just like you'd access the `turnContext`, you can do: `settings.BaseURL`

Answer (score 0):

In Bot Framework Adaptive Dialog I find correct answer and [work fine on Bot Framework Composer](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/experimental/adaptive-dialog/docs/memory-model-overview.md#settings-scope)